# Is there a way to reference the field 'path.virtual' as part of this split processor?

Tags: elasticsearch

The field I am interested in from my ES doc below "virtual":

```
          "path" : {
            "root" : "cda42f809526c222ebb54e5887117139",
            "virtual" : "/tests/3.pdf",
            "real" : "/tmp/es/tests/3.pdf"
          }
```

My simulated ingest pipeline:

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "description": "split words on line_number field",
    "processors": [
      {
        "split": {
          "field": "path.virtual",
          "separator": "/",
          "target_field": "temporary_field"
        }
      },
      {
        "set": {
          "field": "caseno",
          "value": "{{temporary_field.1}}"
        }
      },
      {
        "set": {
          "field": "file",
          "value": "{{temporary_field.2}}"
        }
      },
     
      {
        "remove": {
          "field": "temporary_field"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "path.virtual": "/test/3.pdf"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I change the actual field 'path.virtual' to 'path' or 'virtual' I get desired result but if I use the actual field name I get the following error:

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "error" : {
        "root_cause" : [
          {
            "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "field [[path] not present as part of path [[path.virtual]]"
          }
        ],
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "field [[path] not present as part of path [[path.virtual]]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in simulate:

```
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "path": {
          "virtual": "/test/3.pdf"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```